# Systemd: why isn't it possible to use %i in the first argument of ExecStart=?

Tags: systemd

To quote http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%lines:

> The command line accepts "%" specifiers as described in systemd.unit(5). Note that the first argument of the command line (i.e. the program to execute) may not include specifiers.

I just ran into a use-case where I wanted to do this.

Why is this not possible? Is there a suggested workaround?

Comment: If you've run into this, I strongly suspect something is horribly wrong with your use case. Exactly what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: As to why, you should direct that at the systemd designers/developers.

Comment: A workaround would be to have `ExecStart` call a script, pass it `%i` as a parameter, and have the script start the required binary.

Comment: Yeah, I know it seems off. The problem is the daemon executable takes some of its config info relative to its full path (I know). That's why it's scattered all over the FS in different directories, and separate instances need to be run from separate directories. @larsks: that's what I'm doing right now, thanks.

Comment: Why down vote? I think this is a perfectly fine question. The use case may be off (it annoys me a bit as well), but the question stands.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfect question. Why are they (systemd devs) forcing us to some limitations? This is why I dislike systemd over sysV init scripts or openrc. :/ It's really sad where linux is headed!

Answer (score 3):

According to the author himself (poettering) in [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3061) thread : it is forbiden because the executable name might be needed in advance (e.g.: SELinux needs this).

But according to other in the same thread and in [that](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/2646#issuecomment-185694182) one, is still works sometime-ish.

Given that most specifiers can be determined statically in advance (template, machine, etc.) it should get supported eventually.

In the meantime, one solution is to launch a shell, as noted in the question comments and in the first thread:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "exec opt/%i/bin/service --args"
```

Another solution would be to manually invoke the ELF interpreter:

```
ExecStop=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/local/bin/%i-cli stop
```

(Basically the same idea as manually running `/usr/bin/perl script.pl` instead of trusting the she-bang of the script)

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use `/usr/bin/env`, then run the command after that as normal.

In my case, I wanted to write a non-absolute npm command:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env npm start -- -p 2345
```

In your case you might do something like

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env some-command/%i/bin
```